# How do I use jQuery.noConflict();

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, lightbox, buddypress

After installing lightbox for my website my comments stopped working. I looked at the code and moved the javascript links that were in the `<head>` (the ones that came with lightbox) in the to above the javascript links that came with Wordpress-Buddypress. Before my javascript links from Lightbox were below the javascript links that came with Wordpress.

After making the switch, the comments started working again on my website but now the lightbox does not work.

When I use Firebug to find errors, I get this error.

```
$("#videogallery a[rel]").overlay is not a function
```

That code comes from "videolightbox.js" which was a file that came with my lightbox.

I did lots of reseach on this problem and I am thinking that I might need to use `jQuery.noConflict();` but I have no idea how to use it? I was looking at this [link](http://www.adrogen.com/blog/jquery-conflict-is-not-a-function/)

but I can't seem to get it to work because I have no idea how to use it. I also tried replacing all the `$()` with `jQuery()` but that did not solve my problem.

Comment: Did you replace the $() with jQuery() inside the "videolightbox.js" file?

Comment: Yes, I did do that. What would be the structure of my javascript links from lightbox (in the <head></head> if I do change that? (I can't figure out how to set it up)

Answer (score 1):

> but I have no idea how to use it?

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
```

and your code will change from 
$(selector) to $j(selector)

A lot of examples are given here
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Comment: thank you for your answer. I looked at the link and saw where you are getting this from.. I just am so confused on where I would put that code? Do I put it before my scripts in my <head></head>???

Comment: @user1164029    Just after place where you load jQuery the library. Or anywhere else before your jQuery selectors.

Comment: `<script src="http://www.pokemonsocial.com/jquery.tools.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` That is my script for my first jquery.. I still don't understand where to place that code. Right after where it says "script"?

Comment: @user1164029     <script src="http://www.pokemonsocial.com/jquery.tools.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script> var $j = jQuery.noConflict(); </script> for example, but you have to modify the files which are using jQuery, replacing $(..) with $j(...)

Comment: okay, I did that to just my first jQuery (the one right above) and it didn't work. Do I do that to both files? (I have two files with jQuery)

Comment: @user1164029    it is much easier to see everything in place. right now I see a few errors on your website: $(�#signup-welcome).p(;:last-child').css('display', 'none'); this weird record and here $(document).ready(function(){ $("ul.sf-menu").superfish();}); did you try to fix them at first?

Comment: well i know those errors are there. The errors that I am trying to fix right now is the one on the "pokemonsocial.com/social" page because with those errors on my "social" page, the website cannot even function fully. I was thinking about fixing those errors that you mentioned later.

Comment: it is difficult to discuss all the details in comments here. On the mentioned page jquery.tools.min.js is not found on server (404 error).

Comment: that 404 error is gone now. It only showed that error when I had the script in a certain spot. I have it back to the orginal spot. I looked at both of the jQuery files and they are in fact different versions. I put the newer one on top and the older one below. With the older one, I used the var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
 method and it still doesn't seem to work :/ I know the comments are hard to talk.

Comment: @user1164029    Step by step. At first you should resolve ALL errors appearing on the page. Lightbox is doing noConflict by itself, so there should be now problem. The major problem are errors on the page that are still there. But the video is playing in overlay - you were trying to solve that problem?

Comment: Yes, the video is playing. but when the video is playing, the comments on the social page do not work properly (you have to be logged in to post comments). This is the setup where the lightbox scripts are located below the wordpress scripts. If I move the lightbox scripts above the wordpress scripts, then the comments will work and the lightbox will not

Comment: @user1164029    And, again, you do not need noConflict (remove it) - in global.js you have var jq = jQuery;  the problem is that this one jq('div.activity').click( is not attached to the div style="width:96%;clear:both;margin:auto;" div class="activity" role="main" because function passed to the ready stack (jq(document).ready( function(){.. }) is not called (I checked it). At first I would eliminate any error message, because this problem might be caused by it.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to consider closely is the script loading order and watch for repeat loading of JQuery.  In some (hopefully rare) situations, you can load JQuery, set up some code that uses it, then reload JQuery which tosses away the events that were set up after loading it the first time.

I know I ran into that situation once, but I can't remember the details that led to it occurring.

Comment: I think that might be it. Depending on where I put my scripts for my lightbox, either the comments will stop working or my lightbox will stop working. I looked at my source code and there is `<script src="http://www.pokemonsocial.com/jquery.tools.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` and there is also `<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.pokemonsocial.com/wp-content/plugins/rs-buddypress-activity-refresh/jquery.timeago.js?ver=3.3'></script>` Because both have "jquery" in them, do you think that is causing a conflict?

Comment: There is a distinct possibility that it is your problem, since you're using two potentially different versions of JQuery, but assigning both to `$`.

Comment: yes, i checked and they are both different versions. i still cant get things to work :/

Comment: I suggest posting a new question with the multiple-versions of JQuery as the main issue.  Try some web searching too, this has happened before, I suspect.

Answer (score 0):

To your answer

```
$=jQuery.noConflict();
```

Now you can use $('#id').css(...);

Answer (score 0):

The error is probably causing the rest of the code not being executed, `.overlay` is not a function means that `.overlay` is not a function and `$` is working fine.

```
var test; test("#videogallery a[rel]").test()
//TypeError: test is not a function <-- You would see this if $ wasn't working

var test = function(){return {};};
test("#videogallery a[rel]").test();
//TypeError: test("#videogallery a[rel]").test is not a function <-- You see this because .overlay isn't working
```

It simply means you are trying to call `.overlay` before it exists.